# Stateless initial load with React with token redirect

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux, stateless

what I'm trying to accomplish, simply - is:
1: load index.html > test for token
if token redirect to dashboard
if not, then render login

everything is json object oriented so state is event driven, not application driven.  Because I want to run this as a process service, not a webApp.

I'd like to use React-Redux but of course, these frameworks have this aching need to import crap that isn't used immediately which to me seems rather neolithic. If I don't need it, don't import it. Once an event is triggered, then import what I need.

any ideas?  (ps I come from angular 1.5 primarily and I can do this easily in Angular but haven't been able to wrap my head around this in react).

Answer (score 0):

Where is this token coming from? Is it an AJAX call or you have it already?

Comment: put it as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: the token is in sessionStorage. if it exists, then I (in angular) already have the navigation JSON document, so I don't need routes.

In Angular I have (always) only needed one route

`/:module'
which loads `views/module.html` and then depending on what the module is, I have (already) returned the nested JSON document of that object, ie: dashboard, users, projects, products, or what have you.

Comment: So can't you just create a conditional render inside a higher order component?

Let's say you have App component and inside render you do:
render () {
  return sessionStorage.get("token") ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />
}

Comment: from that point, I simply build the page, avoid partials, and compile the result - using the json document to render the properties, which should - in theory work fine for react, but of course, nope, it doesn't.

Comment: I've tried every permutation of option. I'm finding Front-end development logic is "hey let's hard code everything and call it programming!" I"m a backend system ops guy. I can generate the rules in the db, render the documents in json, and simply spit that to the front end. The front end either A: has a json document and then dynamically build itself, or B: doesn't have a json document and then it's a login page. That shouldn't be brain surgery

Comment: There should be a need for a render, until tests have been completed.
Test 1: does a token exist in sessionStorage? yes -> then redirect to the dashboard unless the user has clicked a module in the navigation, then get that JSON object from the server, now build the page. 
no -> well ok then . no state, nothing. just load a nice static html page with login, and the event of "submit" is now how we load the first json document, navigation, styles, content, etc - once.

Comment: Have a look at this code. This is my suggestion for this case. https://codesandbox.io/s/ypn7546lkx

Comment: @DanielStoyanoff . Cheers! finally! a stateless solution. :) thnx mate. The dependencies on class injections and state is way too over bloated. Trying to make the front end do what the server already does has always struck me as backwards logic, rather than keeping up with what is in fact the nature of programming. :) . This solution, is the only solution! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using Redux here is an adequate choice. You should also consider using React Router as well.

However, minimally, what you're asking for is pretty simple. You just need to have some sort of way to do conditional rendering.

```js
// mock sessionStorage due to sandbox
const mockSessionStorage = { token: true }

const MainPage = () => <h1>Main Page</h1>
const Login = () => <h1>Login</h1>

const AUTHENTICATING = 0
const AUTHENTICATED = 1
const NOT_AUTHENTICATED = 2

const App = ({ authState }) => {
  switch (authState) {
    case AUTHENTICATED:
      return <MainPage />
    case NOT_AUTHENTICATED:
      return <Login />
  }

  return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}

const render = (authState) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App authState={authState} />,
    document.getElementById('root'))
}

const getAuthentication = () => {
  if (mockSessionStorage.token) {
    return render(AUTHENTICATED)
  }
  render(NOT_AUTHENTICATED)
}

render(false)
setTimeout(getAuthentication, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: this is similar to every example I've reviewed for react. it has
```
const MainPage = () => <h1> Main Page </h1>
const Login = () => <h1> Login </h1>
```

there isn't a real world example of 'hey we don't have any idea what we're getting.   It appears react is far too dependent on hard coding everything' instead of being able to simply return random results, which are determined only after a user has logged in.

Comment: To be honest, i'm simply going to return to a nice simple uncomplicated angular 1.5 approach. I don't need to hard code anything and can simply build and compile at runtime, rather than bloat the browser with not required crap

Comment: What is being hardcoded? The component for MainPage and such are left as an exercise to you, to populate it with relevant content. This content can, of course, be fetched via AJAX once the MainPage component is loaded. Is that the part you want help with? Because that's not at all what you asked. And if what you want is AngularJS, feel free to use it -- we're not here to convince you otherwise.